# Add Filter in Pyhton

Tags: selenium

I want to send an e-mail by pulling the advertisement links that I have collected from a site one by one. I wrote a system but it doesn't work, it doesn't give an error either. Namely, if there are certain words and phone numbers in the advertisement, it will not send an e-mail, otherwise it will send an e-mail. I did filters. I am sharing my codes. If there are errors you see when you look at them (such as logic, code errors…) I would be very happy if you could share them.

> Word Filter

```
 try:
        re = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body")
        search_words = re.findAll(
            "Import",
            "Tree",
            "Seven",
        )
        print("\nCannot send mail because it contains the word.Index :", i)
        print(re.findAll)
    except:
        search_words = " "
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**re** will return a WebElement. I think you are looking for the **text** from element? If so, you need to use the (text) property:

```
re = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body").text
```

But to work properly you can do it like this:

```
try:
    web_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body").text
    words = ["Import", "Tree", "Seven"]

    search_words = [word for word in words if re.findall(word, web_text)]
    text_words = ''
    if search_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(search_words):
            if i < len(search_words) - 1:
                text_words += f"{word}, "
            else:
                text_words += f"{word}."
        print(f"\nCannot send mail because it contains the word.Index : {text_words}")
        print(re.findall)
except Exception:
    text_words = ""
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Yes, it's true. Thank you so much. Did you notice any other errors?

Comment: Yes, I added a workable solution above!

Comment: @B.12 this applicable to all the relevant posts. Of cause in case if the answer was useful / resolved the problem